# How to use withColumn to aggregate data from another table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table like the following -

```
table_a
id|start_date|end_date
1|2020-01-01|2020-01-05
...
```

I would like to create an aggregate column in this dataframe using the following table

```
table_b
id|val|date
1|5.0|2020-01-01
1|2.0|2020-01-03
1|6.0|2020-01-08
2|5.0|2020-01-01
3|5.0|2020-01-01
```

I want an aggregate column in table_a of the sum of all values of table_b where table_b's `date` column is between the start and end date of table_a.  How would this be done?

So this final table_a would be -

```
table_a
id|start_date|end_date|agg_col
1|2020-01-01|2020-01-05|7.0
...
```

A follow up question -

How would I compute multiple aggregations based on different factors? (Specifically, flags and date ranges)  I thought about using bucketing, but rows from `table_b` will fall into multiple overlapping ranges.

```
table_a
id|start_date|end_date
1|2020-01-01|2020-01-05
1|2020-01-03|2020-01-07
1|2020-01-04|2020-01-08
2|2020-01-01|2020-01-05
2|2020-01-03|2020-01-07
2|2020-01-04|2020-01-08
```

```
table_b
id|val|date|flag_a|flag_b
1|10.0|2019-12-15|0|0
1|15.0|2019-12-25|0|0
1|5.0|2020-01-01|0|0
1|2.0|2020-01-03|0|4
1|6.0|2020-01-08|3|4
1|4.0|2020-01-18|3|4
2|5.0|2020-01-01|0|3
3|5.0|2020-01-01|0|2
```

The final output would have many different sum aggregate columns all based on different factors.  Some possible aggregations could be -

```
table_b date between (START_DATE - 30 days to START_DATE - 15 days)
table_b date between (START_DATE - 180 days to START_DATE - 90 days)
table_b date between (START_DATE - 10 days to START_DATE +5 days AND flag_a=0)
table_b date between (END_DATE + 5 days to END_DATE +20 days AND flag_b=3)
```

Would a spark function solution be faster pure sql solution that looks like this?  Performance is a huge factor, table_a has 100m rows and table_b has close to 50b rows.  I will be running approximately 50 different aggregations.

```
select *, 
    (select sum(val) from table_b b
    where date > a.start_date - 180
    and date < a.start_date - 90
    and a.id = b.id ) as val_sum_180_90,
    ...
from table_a a
```

a solution like this?

Comment: A table with 50 billion rows? I hope it's partitioned in some way.  

This is the worst kind of join situation you want though, because it's a range join.  Knowing the sizes helps, because it says the biggest pain point would be on table_b.  So pre-aggregating is necessary at last, and you'd switch the join order (would want table_b joining against table_a instead of the other way around).

Comment: Oh wait, it's actually not that hard (I think)!  Let me give it another go.

Comment: @kanielc It is partitioned by the date column!

Comment: That's informative, so if you go with what I suggested below with faster_b, then the resulting table will actually be very small. In that case you could try flipping faster_b and table_a in the join.

Answer (score 2):

First you must perform a join operation and group them:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val tableA = spark.read.[...]
val tableB = spark.read.[...]

val df = tableA.as("tableA").join(tableB.as("tableB"), expr("tableA.id = tableB.id AND tableB.date BETWEEN tableA.start_date AND tableA.end_date"), "inner")

val dfGroup = df.groupBy("tableA.id").agg(min("tableA.start_date").as("start_date"), 
                                          max("tableA.end_date").as("end_date"), 
                                          sum("val").as("agg_col"))
dfGroup.show(false)
```

Output

```
+---+----------+----------+-------+
|id |start_date|end_date  |agg_col|
+---+----------+----------+-------+
|1  |2020-01-01|2020-01-05|7.0    |
+---+----------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Is there anyway to have the date condition be in the aggregation function instead at the join level?  I want to get the aggregations for different ranges as well, so start_date - 90 days to start_date - 30 days, start_date-30days to start_date, etc..  and have a different column for each.  Could I join with the max range so start_date - 90 days to end_date + 90 days, but then filter it down at the sum level?

Comment: @asdasd32 I would recommend you to update your question showing this scenario and the desired output to make easier your problem visualization

Answer (score 1):

You can first join the two tables based on your condition (in this specific case `table_b.date BETWEEN table_a.start_date AND table_a.end_date`) and then group by `table_a.id` like in the following query performing the required aggregation.

```
SELECT table_a.id, FIRST(table_a.start_date) AS start_date, FIRST(table_a.end_date) AS end_date, SUM(table_b.val) AS total
FROM table_a
     LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.date BETWEEN table_a.start_date AND table_a.end_date
GROUP BY table_a.id
```

Using your example, the result is:

```
+---+----------+----------+-----+
| id|start_date|  end_date|total|
+---+----------+----------+-----+
|  1|2020-01-01|2020-01-05| 17.0|
+---+----------+----------+-----+
```

The query is in Spark SQL but it can easily be transformed into Dataframe API:

```
tableA.join(tableB, col("date").between(col("start_date"), col("end_date")), "left")
            .groupBy(tableA.col("id"))
            .agg(
                    first("start_date").as("start_date"),
                    first("end_date").as("end_date"),
                    sum("val").as("total")
            ).show();
```

Comment: In your scala example is needed to create an alias during the join, otherwise your groupBy will throw an error because your dataframe will have ambiguous columns

Comment: Hi @Kafels, the only ambiguous column is `id` which is already referenced as `tableA.col("id")` in the `groupBy()` so it should work fine even without aliases in the join

Comment: Yeah, it's true, I didn't notice you were selecting `tableA.col("id")` at group by operation

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional info, I think we have more understanding of the situation now.

I'll put the code and then explanations below it

```scala
val faster_b = table_b.groupBy('id, 'date).agg(sum('val) as "val") // 1
faster_b.join(table_a, Seq("id")) // 2
 .where('date.between('start_date, 'end_date))  // 3 
 .groupBy("id", "start_date", "end_date").agg(sum('val)) // 4
```

Explanations:
1 - Pre-aggregate table_b to reduce the number of duplicates in a join
2 - Drop ranges in table_a with no matches here, which should be ok.  Since we joined on a numeric column, should be very fast.
3 - Do the filter after the join.  Trade off here is more memory at the join, but much more speed
4 - Do our final aggregation

That outputs

```
scala> res.show(false)
+---+----------+----------+---+
|id |start_date|end_date  |val|
+---+----------+----------+---+
|1  |2020-01-01|2020-01-05|7.0|
+---+----------+----------+---+
```

The thing that saves us here is actually `id` because it's easy to join on.  We give up more memory here, but turn the join into a really fast equi-join.

Give this a try and let me know how it turns out.  It's actually possible to generalize it to handle multiple of your aggregations at once (instead of filtering, creating a column that answers your aggregation question).  I can give more info on that idea if needed.